# what's the proper soldering iron temperature for wave soldered cards using with SACX plus 0307 bars

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station, rework

Hello all we need a proper technique to rework for wave soldered PCB's either SMD or Leaded components . We are using SACX plus 0307 solder bars for wave soldering . Here we have soldering issues with both SMD and Leaded components.
We are using HAKKO 888D soldering irons for wave soldered PCB's rework.
Request to suggest the faster and best rework technics.

Comment: What was the original solder? Find that and you have its melting point.

Comment: I would start by talking to the solder vender and discussing your problem with them. They can give you the information on the solder and what temperatures etc you need. You have good soldering irons but what are you using for SMD?

Comment: Hi Gil thanks for responding and ur concern. What are you using for SMD? means soldering process or something else?